# php strtok doesnt work if delimiter is a first character in the string?

Tags: php, replace, strtok

I have a list of strings that may, or may not contain certain delimiter, and use [strtok](http://in.php.net/strtok) to remove everything after that delimiter in a string, for example:

```
$href = "test#content";
$href = strtok($href,'#');
echo $href;
```

outputs:

```
test
```

I ran into a problem when the string starts with a delimiter though:

```
$href = "#content";
$href = strtok($href,'#');
echo $href;
```

Instead of desired output of '', it outputs:

```
content
```

Why does it not work the same way as in first example and what is the most efficient way to get the desired results with the least of extra code?

Comment: From the manual it states `The behavior when an empty part was found changed with PHP 4.1.0. The old behavior returned an empty string, while the new, correct, behavior simply skips the part of the string:`

Comment: This really comes from a fundamental misunderstanding of what `strtok()` actually does, and an assumption that it's some variant of explode() that simply returns results one at a time

Comment: Why is ignoring empty strings the correct behavior? I can think of many cases where that is what you would want strtok to do. Why did the PHP team not simply add a flag or a PHP directive to specify which behavior the programmer wants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), for returning the left part of delimiter, when the third(`$before_needle`) argument is passed, by default the right site is returned. To check if the delimiter exists or not you can use the [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do the task, it's performe a regular expression, return `true` if the pattern is find or false for fail.

```
$href = "test#content";

if(preg_match('/#/', $href)){
    echo strstr($href, '#', true); //test
}else{
    echo 'delimiter not found';
}
```

Comment: It works as long as the string contains '#', if not it returns empty string. Can't use since only some of my strings contain '#' .

Comment: @Acidon, there aren't a fix delimiter?

Comment: correct, some strings contain delimiters and has to be processed, others don't and should be left as is.

Comment: @acidon then why did you not mention it in your question?

Comment: Maybe because while using strtok it didn't return empty results if delimiter wasn't present and I was hoping to go strtok way and thought I was using it wrong? Anyway, I went your way by adding conditional check,  `if (strpos($href, "#") !== false) { $href = strstr($href, '#', true); }`, I will edit my question and if you will update your answer will accept it

Comment: Preg_match is slower and has a slightly more complex interface as compared with strtok. Why can't strtok optionally return empty strings?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to return everything before '`#`' then you could use explode.

> The behavior when an empty part was found changed with PHP 4.1.0. The
>   old behavior returned an empty string, while the new, correct,
>   behavior simply skips the part of the string.

**TEST 1** (https://3v4l.org/4lP5u):

```
$href = "#content";
$href = explode('#', $href);
echo $href['0'];

//returns ''
```

**TEST 2** (https://3v4l.org/ov9Yl):

```
$href = "test#content";
$href = explode('#', $href);
echo $href['0'];

//returns 'test'
```

***EDIT***:

WHOOPs I added the wrong link in the `TEST 2` example, now updated the link.

As per your comment

> unfortunately I cant go explode route since $href variable will be
>   reused later and cannot be array. Also, there is an incorrect output
>   in the example in your second link because it echoes $href['1']
>   instead of $href['0']

you could:

**TEST 3** (https://3v4l.org/uWPOk):

```
$href = "test#content";
$href = explode('#', $href);
$href = $href['0'];
echo $href;
```

**TEST 4** (https://3v4l.org/rtIJ0) :

This checks if string contains `#` and explodes it else `$href` stays the same

```
$href = "test#content";

if (strpos($href, '#') !== FALSE){
    $href = explode('#', $href);
    $href = $href['0'];
    echo $href;
}else{
    echo "$href";
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I cant go explode route since `$href` variable will be reused later and cannot be array. Also, there is an incorrect output in the example in your second link because it echoes `$href['1']` instead of `$href['0']` .

Comment: @Acidon My bad I added the wrong link. I have since updated that and added a new **test**.

Comment: Why can't strtok optionally return empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `preg_split` might be of use in this situation:

```
$href = "#content";
$pieces=preg_split('@#@',$href);
echo $pieces[0];/* Empty */
echo $pieces[1];/*content*/
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think strtok is ment to be use that way...

read manual here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

but i would have use something like this ...

```
echo substr($href, 0, strpos($href, '#'));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the string before `#` you should use `explode`.A work around for your approach can be something like this:

```
<?php 
$href = "#content";
if($href[0]=='#'){//check the first index character
    $href="''".$href;
}
$href = strtok($href,'#');
echo $href;

?>
```